# Maximum limit of JVM heap size<1/4(Ram Size ) can i say like this

Tags: java

I want to increase my jvm size on 96GB RAM for that i have given -Xmx1600m

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1638400KB object heap
Press any key to continue . . .
I got this Error on  8 GB RAM as well as 96 GB Ram ?
-Xmx1350m is working on 8GB and 96 GB both but beyond  that memory is not working

Comment: how much free ram do you have out of those 8GB that can be allocated to Java? Also how much are you giving to perm or meta space settings

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a 32-bit build of Java (you can confirm by running `java -version`). A 32-bit application can only address a *theoretical* maximum of 4GB, and in reality for the JVM it's often much less than that.

Switching to a 64-bit build of the JVM should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am already using 64bit

C:\Users\akuma142>java -version
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)